# Timer Viewable by multiple users

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

Im am currently developing a simple game that requires a timer. Currently the timer i have only displays for the specific user looking at the page. I want the timer to be the same for all of the users not different for each user. Could someone please point me to an example of something like this?
Thank You

Comment: does the timer ever stop, or is it some kind of reflection of the server time?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is client side, meaning that it will only run on each clients machine individually and not every clients simultaneously. For your countdown timer to be the same for multiple users you would have to use a server side language such as PHP.

Using PHP, along with Javascript or Jquery you could easily implement a system wide countdown timer, however if you only wanted certain users to have this timer you would have to put logic into your PHP code that would check which users are apart of the game.

Here is a link to a tutorial I found, should get your started in the right direction

http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/9471.aspx